# Scaffolding Identity error in ASP.NET 5.0 (WebApp without MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, identity, scaffolding

I wanted to get source pages of Identity and did all actions in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).
I've stopped in `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity -h` because it's throwing error:

```
Usage: aspnet-codegenerator [arguments] [options]

Arguments:
generator  Name of the generator. Check available generators below.

Options:
-p|--project             Path to .csproj file in the project.
-n|--nuget-package-dir   
-c|--configuration       Configuration for the project (Possible values: Debug/ Release)
-tfm|--target-framework  Target Framework to use. (Short folder name of the tfm. eg. net46)
-b|--build-base-path     
--no-build               

Selected Code Generator: identity
No code generator found with the name 'identity'.

No code generators are available in this project.Add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design package to the project as a NuGet package reference.

RunTime 00:00:01.29
```

I have a .NET 5.0 in Arch Linux. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design and other packages installed as 5.0.0.
Project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>USER-SECRETS-ID-CENSORED</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="app.db" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" ExcludeFromSingleFile="true" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.0">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.21.2" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="wwwroot\img" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I have not idea to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

try to uninstall the version you currently have if it's the wrong one :

`dotnet tool uninstall --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`

you have to install the 5.0 version of the dotnet codegenerator with this command :

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator --version 5.0.2`

and type this command to display all the hidden files :

`dotnet aspnet-codegenerator identity`